# A very basic Java calculator that calculates only single digit numbers

Tags: java, calculator, swing

How should I incorporate a JButton array, and how do I get rid of the multitude of action listeners? I would also like to modify it so that you can do more than one operation on numbers with multiple digits.

```
/*
 * A one operation calculator.
 * Only handles single digits for basic arithmetic.
 * Trig operations accept values in degrees.
 * 
 * I'll make a real calculator later.
 */

public class BasicCalculator extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;                   
    private JTextField input;   
    private JButton butt0, butt1, butt2, butt3,
                    butt4, butt5, butt6, butt7,
                    butt8, butt9, buttSine, buttCosine,
                    buttEquals, buttClear, buttAdd,
                    buttSubtract, buttMultiply, buttDivide,
                    buttTangent;
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 360;   
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300;

/*
 * Constructor calls the superclass's constructor and creates the window.
 */
    public BasicCalculator() {

        super("Calculate a Simple Expression");

        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        buildPanel();

        add(panel);

        setVisible(true);

    }

/*
 * Method to put the input box and all the buttons onto the window.
 * 
 * I know, I know, I should've used an array for the buttons.
 */
    private void buildPanel() {

        input = new JTextField(16);

        buttEquals = new JButton("=");
        buttEquals.addActionListener(new Listener1());
        buttClear = new JButton("AC");
        buttClear.addActionListener(new Listener2());
        buttAdd = new JButton("+");
        buttAdd.addActionListener(new Listener3());
        buttSubtract = new JButton("-");
        buttSubtract.addActionListener(new Listener4());
        buttMultiply = new JButton("x");
        buttMultiply.addActionListener(new Listener5());
        buttDivide = new JButton("÷");
        buttDivide.addActionListener(new Listener6());
        butt0 = new JButton("0");
        butt0.addActionListener(new Listener7());
        butt1 = new JButton("1");
        butt1.addActionListener(new Listener8());
        butt2 = new JButton("2");
        butt2.addActionListener(new Listener9());
        butt3 = new JButton("3");
        butt3.addActionListener(new Listener10());
        butt4 = new JButton("4");
        butt4.addActionListener(new Listener11());
        butt5 = new JButton("5");
        butt5.addActionListener(new Listener12());
        butt6 = new JButton("6");
        butt6.addActionListener(new Listener13());
        butt7 = new JButton("7");
        butt7.addActionListener(new Listener14());
        butt8 = new JButton("8");
        butt8.addActionListener(new Listener15());
        butt9 = new JButton("9");
        butt9.addActionListener(new Listener16());
        buttSine = new JButton("sin");
        buttSine.addActionListener(new Listener17());
        buttCosine = new JButton("cos");
        buttCosine.addActionListener(new Listener18());
        buttTangent = new JButton("tan");
        buttTangent.addActionListener(new Listener19());

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 30));

        panel.add(input);

        panel.add(buttEquals);
        panel.add(buttClear);
        panel.add(buttAdd);
        panel.add(buttSubtract);
        panel.add(buttMultiply);
        panel.add(buttDivide);
        panel.add(butt0);
        panel.add(butt1);
        panel.add(butt2);
        panel.add(butt3);
        panel.add(butt4);
        panel.add(butt5);
        panel.add(butt6);
        panel.add(butt7);
        panel.add(butt8);
        panel.add(butt9);
        panel.add(buttSine);
        panel.add(buttCosine);
        panel.add(buttTangent);

    }

/*
 * Action listener for the "equals" button.
 * All the calculations are done here.
 */
    private class Listener1 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String str = input.getText();

            double num1, num2, radians, result;

            if (str.charAt(0) == 's' || str.charAt(0) == 'c' || str.charAt(0) == 't') 
            {
                radians = Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(str.substring(3)));

                switch (str.charAt(0)) {

                    case 's':
                        result = Math.sin(radians);
                        break;
                    case 'c':
                        result = Math.cos(radians);
                        break;
                    case 't':
                        result = Math.tan(radians);
                        break;
                    default:
                        result = 0; 
                }
            }   
            else 
            {
                num1 = Double.parseDouble(str.substring(0, 1));
                num2 = Double.parseDouble(str.substring(4, 5));

                switch (str.charAt(2)) {

                    case '+':
                        result = num1 + num2;
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        result = num1 - num2;
                        break;
                    case 'x':
                        result = num1 * num2;
                        break;
                    case '÷':
                        result = num1 / num2;
                        break;
                    default:
                        result = 0;
                }
            }

            input.setText(Double.toString(result)); 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str + " = " + result);

        }
    }

/*
 * The rest of the action listeners print the button text to the text field.
 */
    private class Listener2 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText("");
        }
    }
    private class Listener3 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + " + ");
        }
    }
    private class Listener4 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + " - ");
        }
    }
    private class Listener5 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + " x ");
        }
    }
    private class Listener6 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + " ÷ ");
        }
    }
    private class Listener7 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + "0");
        }
    }
    private class Listener8 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + "1");
        }
    }
    private class Listener9 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + "2");
        }
    }
    private class Listener10 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + "3");
        }
    }   
    private class Listener11 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + "4");
        }
    }

    private class Listener12 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + "5");
        }
    }
    private class Listener13 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + "6");
        }
    }
    private class Listener14 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + "7");
        }
    }
    private class Listener15 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + "8");
        }
    }
    private class Listener16 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + "9");
        }
    }
    private class Listener17 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + "sin");
        }
    }
    private class Listener18 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + "cos");
        }
    }
    private class Listener19 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            input.setText(input.getText() + "tan");
        }
    }

/*
 * main method
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new BasicCalculator();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have implementations consisting of just single line.
For example, you can replace the `Listener2` direclty with a lambda as :

```
buttClear = new JButton("AC");
buttClear.addActionListener(event ->  input.setText(""));
```

Same goes will all one liner `Listener`s in your code.

There's also a bug in your code because of the way you are extracting numbers from the input field.
If you perform `4/3`, you will get the result as `1.3333333`, and if you continue doing more operations like `1.333333*3`, your calculator returns the result as `0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the power of classes: they encapsulate a common concept, so that you write them once, and reuse them multiple times. (And all in all this is the main act of programming: spot common patterns and derieve generalizations from these patterns.)

So, you have multiple classes along the lines of:

```
private class Listener17 implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        input.setText(input.getText() + "sin");
    }
}
private class Listener18 implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        input.setText(input.getText() + "cos");
    }
}
```

... which differ only in the text you append. Thus, make ONE class of these, and pass the text to append as a parameter:

```
private class AppendingTextListener implements ActionListener {
    private final String textToAppend;

    AppendingTextListener(String textToAppend) {
        this.textToAppend = textToAppend;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        input.setText(input.getText() + textToAppend);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
butt0.addActionListener(new AppendingTextListener("0"));
butt1.addActionListener(new AppendingTextListener("1"));
...
```